# How to create continuous tunes with audio elements

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am trying to make a simple piano based on Do Re Mi etc keys. My idea is, each sound (Do Re Mi..) will be played corresponding to the keypress event. I am collecting each valid audio element in an array in the order they are chosen by keypress. Later, once user will press the "play" button, all the sounds will be played together as a tune.

Things are working fine so far. However, during the tune playing all the sounds are played together. Seems like, they are overlapped with each other. I want the pause to be added after each sound the way they were initially played.

> Ex : Do (2s pause), Re(no Pause)Re, (1s pause)Mi, Do(3s pause),....

I tried to add pause with a sleep function but it is not working. In my console output the array elements (where the audio elements and corresponding pauses are collected) are printed correctly and the pause is also taken correctly however, during the audio play the pause is not maintained. Any help is very much appreciated. Here is my code,

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <head>
    <title>do-re-mi keyboard</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   </head>
   <body>
    <div id="main-div">
        <h1>Let's create some awesome music ....</h1>
        <div class="keys">
            <div data-key="68" class="musicKey"><p>D</p><span>(Do)</span></div>
            <div data-key="82" class="musicKey"><p>R</p><span>(Re)</span></div>
            <div data-key="77" class="musicKey"><p>M</p><span>(Mi)</span></div>
            <div data-key="70" class="musicKey"><p>F</p><span>(Fa)</span></div>
            <div data-key="83" class="musicKey"><p>S</p><span>(So)</span></div>
            <div data-key="76" class="musicKey"><p>L</p><span>(La)</span></div>
            <div data-key="84" class="musicKey"><p>T</p><span>(Ti)</span></div>
            <button id="playTune">Play</button>
            <button id="refresh">Refresh</button>
        </div>

    </div> <!--main div ends -->
    <audio data-key="68" src="audio/do.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
    <audio data-key="82" src="audio/re.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
    <audio data-key="77" src="audio/mi.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
    <audio data-key="70" src="audio/fa.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
    <audio data-key="83" src="audio/so.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
    <audio data-key="76" src="audio/la.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
    <audio data-key="84" src="audio/ti.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>

    <script src="soundBox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   </body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    margin:0;
}

#main-div{

    height:100vh;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #ffffcc;
    background:url('image/sand.jpg');
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:0;
    padding-top: 50px;
    font-family: 'Rouge Script', cursive; 
    font-size: 40px; font-weight:bolder; 
    line-height: 48px; margin: 0 0 20px;
    color: #e65c00;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #803300; 
}

.keys{
    height: 200px;
    width:700px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    background-color:yellow;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    align-items: center;
}

.musicKey{
    height : 80px;
    width:80px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color:red;
    margin-top:60px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    float:left;
    align-items:center;
   /* box-shadow: inset -3px -5px 2px 1px #515151;*/
    text-align:center;
    transition:all 0.07s;
}

.musicKey span{
    text-align:center;
    font-size: medium;
    padding-top:30px;
}

.musicKeyPressed{
    transform:scale(1.1);
    border-color:black;
    box-shadow: 3px 1px 1px 1px #515151;
}

#playTune{
    float:right;
    height:40px;
    width:80px;
    background-color:gray;
    margin:10px;
}

#refresh{

    float:right;
    height:40px;
    width:80px;
    background-color:green;
    margin:10px;

}
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.addEventListener("keydown",playMusic);

let keyArr = document.querySelectorAll(".musicKey");

var audioKeyProp = {};
var tune = [];
var keyCount =0;
var start =0;
var oldStart =0;

function sleepFunc(time) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > time){
      break;
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById("refresh").addEventListener("click",function(){
    tune = [];
    start =0;
    oldStart =0;
    keyCount =0;
});

document.getElementById("playTune").addEventListener("click",function(){

    //console.log("tune array = " + tune);
    if(tune.length > 0)
    {
        tune.forEach(function(item){
           // console.log("tune item = "+ item);
            if(typeof(item) === "number")
            {
                sleepFunc(item);
            }
            else
            {
                item.play();
                item.currentTime=0;
            }

            });
    }

});

keyArr.forEach(function(item){

    let tempVal = item.getAttribute('data-key');
    audioKeyProp[tempVal] = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${tempVal}"]`);
});

function backToOriginalPosition(e)
{
    if(e.propertyName !== "transform") return;
    this.classList.remove("musicKeyPressed");
}

function playMusic(event)
{
    var pressedKey = event.keyCode;
    var timeElapse = 0;
    start = new Date().getTime();

    if(keyCount >= 1)
    {
        timeElapse = start - oldStart;
    }

    var keyDiv = document.querySelector(`div[data-key="${pressedKey}"]`);
    var audioElement = audioKeyProp[pressedKey];

    if(audioElement && keyDiv)
    {
        console.log("duration= " + audioElement.duration);
        oldStart = start;
        keyCount++;
        tune.push(timeElapse);
        tune.push(audioElement);

        audioElement.currentTime =0;
        audioElement.play();
        keyDiv.classList.add("musicKeyPressed");
        keyDiv.addEventListener("transitionend",backToOriginalPosition);
    }
   }
```

Comment: Don't block the UI thread.  Instead, use `setTimeout`.

Comment: Tried with setTimeout also. It's not working. The audio sounds are not paused correctly.

Comment: Where are `2s`, `1s`, and `3s` derived from?

Comment: These are random times taken between each note (do, re, mi....) while pressing the keys corresponding to each note (do, re, mi....)

Comment: @SLaks... thank you for the hint of setTimeout than setInterval. I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring a variable outside a `setInterval` which will be equal to 0, let's say `var noteIndex = 0`. Inside the `setInterval` play the first note: `tune[noteIndex]` and then increment `noteIndex`.

So your code should be something like that:

```
var tune = [];                      //Set tunes to play
var pause = [];                     //Set tunes breaks
var noteIndex = 0;

var playNotes = setInterval(function(){
    tune[noteIndex].play();
    noteIndex++;
    if (noteIndex > tune.length) {  //Stop the interval if all notes are played.
        noteIndex = 0;              //Reset 'noteIndex' for next use.
        break;
    }
}, pause[noteIndex]);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for the help. Well this will play all the notes after an equall interval of 500 ms. In reality, the note keys might be pressed with different time intervals. I want to play the tune the way keys are pressed.

Comment: @sandy I edited the code to better suit your need. check it out:

Add a `pause` array variable and set the break time you need. When a user set a note to be played and it's length, the `tune` variable takes the note to play and `pause` variable takes the time gap you need.

So `tune[0]` will have `pause[0]` break after it, `tune[1]` will have `pause[1]` break after it and so on.

Comment: Hello @Omer thank you for your effort.... I also solved it. I used recursive setTimeout and it is working as I want. With recursive setTimeout I can pass different time pause so I don't need to pass a separate pause as you used for each setInterval.  setTimeout is better than setInterval in running program after certain interval .... here is the link for knowledge boosting [link](https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval)